# array of items with categories to categories with items

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How do i convert an array of items with categories to categories with items as object?

Input array of items

```
var items = [
    {
        itemId: 111111,
        title: 'Item-1',
        sellerName: 'seller-1',
        category: 'Electronics, Fitness'
    },
    {
        itemId: 222222,
        title: 'Item-2',
        sellerName: 'seller-2',
        category: 'Cars'
    },
    {
        itemId: 333333,
        title: 'Item-3',
        sellerName: 'seller-3',
        category: 'Electronics'
    },
    {
        itemId: 444444,
        title: 'Item-4',
        sellerName: 'seller-4',
        category: 'Cars, Bikes'
    }

]

//Result
    var result = {
        Electronics: [
            {
                itemId: 111111,
                title: 'Item-1',
                sellerName: 'seller-1' 
            },
            {
                itemId: 333333,
                title: 'Item-3',
                sellerName: 'seller-3'
            }
        ],
        Cars: [
            {
                itemId: 222222,
                title: 'Item-2',
                sellerName: 'seller-2'
            },
            {
                itemId: 444444,
                title: 'Item-4',
                sellerName: 'seller-4'
            }
        ],
        Bikes: [
            {
                itemId: 444444,
                title: 'Item-4',
                sellerName: 'seller-4'
            }
        ],

        Fitness: [
            {
                itemId: 111111,
                title: 'Item-1',
                sellerName: 'seller-1'
            }
        ]
    }
```

I tried this code, but doesnt give me the exact result in the format i want:

```
function convertItemsToCategories(items){
var categories = {};
var itemarr = [];
for(var i =0; i < items.length; i++){
  //categories.push(items[i].category.split(','));
  var singleCategory = items[i].category.split(',');
  //categories[items[i].category] = items[i];
  singleCategory.forEach(function(catname){
    if(catname == items[i].category)
     itemarr.push(items[i]);
     categories[catname] = itemarr;
  });

  console.log(singleCategory);
}

console.log(categories);
}

convertItemsToCategories(items);
```

Comment: What does your code give you and how is it different from what you want? I notice that the `category` attribute has white space but you are splitting only on the commas. Could that be part of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> singleCategory.forEach(function(catname){
>   if(catname == items[i].category)
>    itemarr.push(items[i]);
>    categories[catname] = itemarr;
> });
> ```

This part code is not correct. `catname` is "categories" separated by "," and `category` is original categories. And you keep pushing items in `itemarr` without clear it, so the result is very odd.

Please check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uwzo6c9y/).

Comment: Love the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(catname == items[i].category)
```

does not check single word for single word. You can use `RegExp` `/\s|,/` at `.split()` to remove both space and `,` characters from array, `.filter()` with parameter `Boolean` to remove possible empty array items; `Object.hasOwnProperty` to check if property is defined at object, if not create property at object, `for..in` loop to set properties and values excluding `category` to new object, `.push()` object to array.

```
function convertItemsToCategories(items) {
  var categories = {};
  var itemarr = [];

  for(var i =0; i < items.length; i++){
    var currCat = items[i].category.split(/\s|,/).filter(Boolean);
    for (var j = 0; j < currCat.length; j++) {
      var obj = {};
      if (!categories.hasOwnProperty(currCat[j])) {
        categories[currCat[j]] = [];
      } 
      for (var prop in items[j]) {
        if (prop !== "category") {
          obj[prop] = items[j][prop]
        }
      }
      categories[currCat[j]].push(obj)       
    }
  }    
console.log(categories);
}
```